Create Bounded DataStream from Iceberg FlinkSource
I am writing a Java application on Flink 1.19 to read Iceberg data (stored on a S3 bucket) using Iceberg FlinkSource and run a SQL query on it using Flink's Batch execution mode.
Here is a code snippet:
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

Map<String, String> props = Map.of(...);
Configuration hadoopConfig = ...;
CatalogLoader catalogLoader =
   CatalogLoader.custom("glue", props, hadoopConfig, "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog");
TableIdentifier tableIdentifier = TableIdentifier.of("db", "iceberg_data");
TableLoader tableLoader = TableLoader.fromCatalog(catalogLoader, tableIdentifier);

DataStream<RowData> stream = FlinkSource.forRowData()
            .env(env)
            .tableLoader(tableLoader)
            .streaming(false)
            .build();
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(
            stream,
            Schema.newBuilder()
                .column(...)
                ...
                .build());
tableEnv.createTemporaryView("iceberg_source", table);

Table res = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM iceberg_source");
tableEnv.toDataStream(res).print();
env.execute("Iceberg example");

However, it fails with below error:
Querying an unbounded table '*anonymous_datastream_source$1*' in batch mode is not allowed. The table source is unbounded.

According to official Iceberg's documentation if "startSnapshotId" is not set, then generated DataStream is bounded. However, exploring created DataStream, I can see it is "CONTINUOUS_UNBOUNDED" and by going thru calls in FlinkSource code, I can see it makes a call to Flink StreamExecutionEnvironment's createInput and then addSource API which always adds a "CONTINUOUS_UNBOUNDED" DataStreamSource.
Any suggestions on why I don't see the expected behavior descried by Iceberg documentation and how one can create a DataStream/Table from an Iceberg FlinkSource that is supported by Flink's Batch mode execution?
